# Determining the convergence of improper integrals?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

So it's given that

$g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are both greater than $0$ for all $x$ values

$\displaystyle\int_1^\infty g(x)dx$ converges,

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 g(x)dx$ diverges, and

$e^{-x} \le h(x) \le \frac{1}x{}$ for all $x$ in $(0,\infty)$.

Given this, how are we then able to know that

$\displaystyle\int_1^\infty g(x)h(x)dx$ converges, and

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 g(x)h(x)dx$ diverges?

Comment: Is $g$ assumed to be nonnegative?

Comment: @zhw. both g and h are positive for all values of x; I've added this bit of detail to my question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\int_1^{\infty} h(x)g(x) \leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac{g(x)}{x} \leq \int_1^{\infty} g(x) < \infty
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{1} h(x)g(x) \geq\int_0^{1} g(x) e^{-x} \geq \int_1^{\infty} g(x)\frac{1}{e}
\end{equation}

which diverges.

Comment: Wow, that is impressive...

Comment: That last  integral should be $\int_1^\infty g(x)\cdot (1/e)$

Comment: Thanks! (corrected)